# Send an email in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, email

I am new at react native. I have a text input area in my app. I want to send the text that user wrote to my gmail . How can I do that?

Here my codes:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { View, Text, TextInput } from "react-native"
import ModalButton from "./ModalButton"
import styles from "./theme"



const StoreReview = (props) => {

    const [comment, setComment] = useState('')

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.headerText}>
                We are very sorry about this.
                Can you share your experiences?
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.commentArea}>
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={setComment}
                    value={comment}
                    multiline={true}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <ModalButton
                    buttonText={'Send'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        console.log(comment, 'send that commet to gmail')
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
export default StoreReview
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking) module with the `mailto` scheme to open the mail app.

Import the `Linking` module:

```js
import { Linking } from 'react-native';
```

Then, use its `openURL()` function to open the mail app:

```
await Linking.openURL('mailto:youremail@example.com');
```

You can also use the `canOpenURL()` function to check if the link is supported:

```
const url = 'mailto:youremail@example.com';

const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);

if (supported) {
  await Linking.openURL(url);
}
```

So, in your example, that'd look like:

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Linking } from 'react-native';
import ModalButton from './ModalButton';

const StoreReview = (props) => {
    const [comment, setComment] = useState('');

    const emailAddress = 'youremail@example.com';
    const url = `mailto:${emailAddress}?body=${comment}`;

    const handlePress = useCallback(async () => {
        const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);

        if (supported) {
            await Linking.openURL(url);
        }
    }, [url]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.headerText}>
                We are very sorry about this.
                Can you share your experiences?
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.commentArea}>
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={setComment}
                    value={comment}
                    multiline={true}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <ModalButton
                    buttonText="Send"
                    onPress={handlePress}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

export default StoreReview;
```

---

**Edit:** I just realized you want to include the `comment` in the email's body.

To set the email subject and body, simply change your URL from `mailto:youremail@example.com` to `mailto:youremail@example.com?subject=Hello&body=World`.

So, in your case, the URL should be:

```js
const [comment, setComment] = useState('');

const emailAddress = 'youremail@example.com';
const url = `mailto:${emailAddress}?body=${comment}`;
```

Comment: I did as you said. I have a new question about this topic, can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69436063/writing-texts-in-the-body-of-the-sent-email-one-under-the-other-react-native/69436285?noredirect=1#comment122729203_69436285

Comment: Sure thing! I posted an answer there.