# Writing texts in the body of the sent email one under the other -React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to React native and javascript. In the application, I created a screen for the user to email me their thoughts. All the texts in the body text of the mail stand side by side. But I want them to be one after the other. How can I provide this? Here is the email I got:

[image]

I want it to be like this:

[image]

My code:

```js
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react"
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, Linking } from "react-native"
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

import { colors } from "../../theme/Colors"
import Fonts from "../../theme/Fonts"
import { units } from "../../theme/Units"
import ModalButtonWithBackground from "./ModalButtonWithBackground"



const StoreReview = (props) => {

    const [comment, setComment] = useState('')

    let brand = DeviceInfo.getBrand();
    let model = DeviceInfo.getModel()

    let body = (brand + ' ' + model )

    const emailAddress = ['example@gmail.com', 'example2@gmail.com'];
    const url = `mailto:${emailAddress}?subject=${'Error'}&body=${body + " " + comment}`;

    const sendEmail = useCallback(async () => {
        const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);

        if (supported) {
            await Linking.openURL(url);
        }
    }, [url]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.commentArea}>
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={setComment}
                    value={comment}
                    multiline={true}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <ModalButtonWithBackground
                    buttonText={'Send'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        sendEmail()
                        props.onPressCloseModal()
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginTop: units.height / 144,
        height: units.height / 2.88,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    headerText: {
        fontFamily: Fonts.type.bold,
        fontSize: Fonts.size(20),
        color: colors.WHITE,
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: units.width / 7.87
    },
    commentArea: {
        width: units.width / 1.13,
        height: units.height / 7.2,
        backgroundColor: colors.WHITE,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
    button: {
        marginTop: 4
    }
})

export default StoreReview
```

Comment: please share your comment section codes .

Comment: comment is writing by user at text input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `\n` *newline character* in your [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
const [comment, setComment] = useState('');

const brand = DeviceInfo.getBrand();                 // Sony
const model = DeviceInfo.getModel();                 // G8341
const systemName = DeviceInfo.getSystemName();       // Android
const systemVersion = DeviceInfo.getSystemVersion(); // 9

const emailAddresses = [
  'example@gmail.com',
  'example2@gmail.com',
];

const to = emailAddresses.join(',');
const subject = 'Error';
const body = `${brand} ${model}\n${systemName} ${systemVersion}\n${comment}`;

const url = `mailto:${to}?subject=${subject}&body=${body}`;

// …
```

For a `Comments here` comment, this will create a new email, ready to be sent to both `example@gmai.com` and `example2@gmai.com`, with a subject of `Error` and the following body.

Body:

```
Sony G8341
Android 9
Comments here
```

---

Here's a somewhat simplified [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/kwM9b4dEI) (check the `components/EmailComposer.js` file)

Comment: I tried the "template literal" document, now I understand it much better. Thank you so much! But I have one more question. Even if you send an e-mail with only "emailAddresses" without putting the e-mail addresses in the "to" variable, the process is completed. Is there an extra reason why we do this with "to"?

Comment: Happy to help! The `emailAddresses.join(',')` is just so I can explicitly convert an array into a comma-separated string. When you're including an array in a template literal, you're basically achieving the same thing, implicitly. Basically, that's equivalent to `emailAddresses.toString()`. You could use either one of them, I simply prefer to be as explicit as possible. Hope that clears it up :)